# Delete comment on mobile version shows weird-looking combination of icon and letters

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, mobile-web, deleted-comments

This probably is a bug. When I tried to delete my comment on the mobile version (particularly, Android mobile, Chrome browser, Stack Overflow's post), I noticed this strange looking combination of delete icon and "de"-letters. Is this intended or a bug?

**Edit:**

The phenomenon only happen when doing *reviewing*. When we normally browse using mobile version, it is actually OK.

---

**Before vs After, on Reviewing:**

[image]

---

**When Not Reviewing, it is OK:**

[image]

---

**Original Post, Bigger Look:**

1. Before Deleting

[image]

2. Deleting

[image]

3. Cancel Deleting

[image]

Comment: @Paweł year later, did you have a chance to review this?

Answer (score 3):

So what happens here is, if the mobile theme is active then comments render with text for the delete link, whereas if the the desktop theme is active then comments render without text and the desktop theme's stylesheet renders 'em as that little icon.

Problem is... There's no mobile theming for review, so the normal desktop theme stylesheets load and try to draw the icon over the top of the text.

If you're thinking, "wait, what? Shouldn't this be done with media queries and some content: rule magic all in the relevant stylesheet?" - yes, yes it should. This is old and crufty and hopefully soon we'll have [a proper responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309349/left-nav-responsive-design-and-theming-next-steps) and can ditch all this "mobile theme" nonsense.

But until then... I've adjusted the renderer to simply drop the `delete-tag` class entirely when rendering comments with an active mobile theme, thus ensuring that you still get a delete link even when the current page has desktop-theme styles.

[image: screenshot showing delete link]