# What do the colors indicate on the SE site cloud?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

https://stackexchange.com/sites

Is it personalized? Because I can't see why some are colored and some maintain the default color. If it is, then maybe I have visited the colored sites at some point(I don't have an account to half of them, but hot cross questions are attracting)?

[image]

Comment: those sites have/had a custom design. With this new responsive design overhaul I believe the distinction between "beta", graduated and fully graduated (with design) will diminish. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309349/left-nav-responsive-design-and-theming-next-steps

Comment: and related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314979/rollout-of-responsive-design-site-themes-tracking-post

Comment: (Lately) You always answer in the comments section @rene... Thanks though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of those colors correspond to the color of the top bar of those sites, which all have a custom design. There are some exceptions, maybe because of the design overhaul.

E.g. [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

and [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

If it's not the top bar color, it's another color which resurfaces in the design of the site.

The colors are the same for everybody and do not depend on whether you have an account or not.